# MVC3 Job Scheduler - XML Export

Tags: sql-server, xml, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-services

I am new to the community and looking forward to being a contributing member.  I wanted to throw this out there and see if anyone had an advice:

I am currently in the middle of developing a MVC 3 app that controls various SQL Jobs.  It basically allows user to schedule jobs to be completed in the future, but also also allows them to run jobs on demand.

I was thinking of having a thread run in the web app that pulls entity information into an XML file, and writing a window service to monitor this file to perform the requested jobs.  Does this sound like a good method? Has anyone done something like this before and used a different approach? Any advice would be great.  I will keep the forum posted on progress and practices.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you running into some issues using a file for complex communication between processes - files can generally only be written by one process at a time, so what happens if the worker process tries to remove a task at the same time as the web process tries to add a task?

A better approach would be to store the tasks in a database that is accessible to both processes - a database can be written to by multiple processes, and it is easy to select all tasks that have a scheduled date in the past.

Using a database you don't get to use FileSystemWatcher, which I suspect is one of the main reasons you want to use a file. If you really need the job to run instantly there are various sorts of messaging you could use, but for most purposes you can just check the queue table on a timer.